# Google sign in validating google ID

Tags: php, google-oauth

I am trying to incorporate a google sign in to a web page. I've followed the documentation and am using this script:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token; 
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?id_token='+id_token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.onload = function() {
  console.log('Signed in as: ' + xhr.responseText);
};
xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);
}
```

I don't really understand the next bit, though - I can see the responseText object, but what do I do with it? I only want to verify that the user is from our work, ie has an email address from our domain (it's a google apps for work gmail). Once it's verified I want to make a php post to a different API, but any sorts of checks that I can think of making at the back end seem to be very easy to spoof to me. I see that there's php library for authenticating tokens [here](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Client.php#L480) but I don't know what I'm supposed to do with that, either. Can anybody give me a pointer?

**[EDIT: info added below]**

So, the response I get back is a JSON object like this (meaningful values replaced with random strings):

```
{
 "iss": "accounts.google.com",
 "at_hash": "e2CYheQnJjpBfyS2StkM9D",
 "aud": "168479532489-Y23kc3sHhn9frJ65Bwtx8Ff4Xdq5RqSH.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "sub": "56798241598765321849762",
 "email_verified": "true",
 "azp": "168479532489-Y23kc3sHhn9frJ65Bwtx8Ff4Xdq5RqSH.apps.googleusercontent.com",
 "hd": "example.com",
 "email": "lucas@example.com",
 "iat": "1444085795",
 "exp": "1444089395",
 "name": "Lucas Smith",
 "given_name": "Lucas",
 "family_name": "Smith",
 "locale": "en",
 "alg": "GU788",
 "kid": "jyaKrpekvYhcRx6KpYSbKhAdYYScLNbEqxqMfCY7"
}
```

Now, according to [this](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) I still need to check that the aud claim contains one of my app's client IDs and I can also check that the hosted domain (hd key here) matches our domain.

So, the question becomes: if I send that JSON object to a php page via ajax, then compare the strings in the object with the ones that I get from the developer console - I'm guessing using `strcmp()` - is that all I need to do? And if they match, do what I wanted to do (call the other API, etc, etc)?

Sorry for the overcautiousness. I have nearly zero experience in php and serverside authentication and really have no idea how easy it would be to spoof a system like this. I guess it could look secure but leave a door wide open for someone wanting to sneak their way in. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: @deek - Why even recommend this? The code is 100% readable and they are doing things just fine. This is not an ajax problem. With your recommendation they would still have the same question "What to do with the data".

Comment: check  this https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Comment: Lucas, can you tell us what the output is in the console (removing personal info)?

Comment: @jesse, he seems a bit lost. jquery's implementation of Ajax is really easy to use.

Comment: @deek - do you work for jquery? Why are we talking about jquery in a non jquery post. This offers no assistance to the OPs question

Comment: Ha ha, thanks @deek but the client side stuff is working fine (which is why I can see the responseText object).  jQuery would not help me one iota here. The link posted by sandeepsure looks promising. Will post back if I have any problems

Answer (score 1):

so, in case anybody finds this at some later date, here's what I ended up doing (caveat: I have no idea if this is the safest way, but it seems OK to me)...

1. posted the id_token to my php page
2. posted the id token to
   `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo` via curl
3. got the response object back from curl, checked it against the aud
   and the hd
       with simple `===` comparisons
4. if they check out, do the API thing

I hope that helps somebody. If there's something disastrously wrong with this approach, please let me know!